# Funcion boolean con entity framework c# Error CS0029

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo la siguiente función creada en mi bd sql, La cual devuelve un único resultado.

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fn_Find_Paciente_Cedula]
(@COD VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
return(
select PAC_CODIGO AS COD,
PAC_NOMBRE AS NOMBRE,
PAC_APELLIDO AS APELLIDO,
PAC_RUT AS CEDULA, 
PAC_DIRECCION AS DIRECCION,
PAC_TELEFONO AS TELCASA,
PAC_CORREO AS CORREO,
PAC_FECHA_NAC AS FECHA,
PAC_OBSERVACIONES AS OBSERVACION,
PAC_COD_ODONT AS CODODONT
FROM TBL_PACIENTE
 WHERE PAC_RUT =@COD)
```

Ahora haciendo uso de `Entity Framework` llamo a la función de la siguiente manera

```
public bool Buscar_Paciente_RUT(string RUT)
    {
        DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES();
        var load_pac = db.fn_Find_Paciente_Cedula(RUT);
        return load_pac.ToList(); --> Error CS0029
    }
```

No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo `System.Collections.Generic.List<> en bool`

Como podría convertir esta función en un boolean ya que posteriormente utilizado el resultado para saber si ese dato ya esta ingresado en la base de dato.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: En lugar de `return load_pac.ToList()` usa `return load_pac.Count() > 0`

Comment: gracias @Lobos efectivamente esa es la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para no dejar la pregunta sin respuesta, adjunto el codigo final, agradezco la ayuda brindada para la resolucion del mismo.

```
 public bool Buscar_Paciente_Ingresado_RUT(string RUT)
    {
        DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES();
        var load_pac = db.fn_Find_Paciente_Cedula(RUT);
        return load_pac.Count() > 0;
    }
```

Con esto me permite validar si la cedula existe previamente y arrojar un mensaje de error para que no la vuelva a ingresar.

Comment: Al select de la función SQL deberías agregar un TOP(1), o en último caso a esta función de C# deberías colocar `return load_pac.Any()`. Un count debe recorrer toda la lista para contar los elemento, en cambio el `Any` recorre hasta que se cumple la condición, y en caso de no tener condición hasta que encuentra el primer elemento